# Visual Studio Code can not run my nim code

Tags: visual-studio-code, nim-lang

[image]

when i click the vscode run button it pops up with a useless dialog box instead of running the code. (i attached a screen)
running with f6 yeilds this error "A system error occurred (EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'c:\0pyrhton\nimtest\C:\Users\L.nimble\bin')"

i was expecting it to compile and run the `.nim` file and alert me to any errors in the vscode terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the nim extension, you can look for an nim extension to your liking, otherwise https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kosz78.nim is an extension that can run .nim files

Comment: i have allready installed the nim exstension.

Comment: then try pressing f6 to run your code

Comment: gives a differant error "A system error occurred (EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'c:\0pyrhton\nimtest\C:\Users\L\.nimble\bin')"

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to install the extension.

This is point 5 in the screenshot

Comment: what do you think the word "useless" means? look i allready tried that and the extension that pops up is litterally for node js and installing it has no effect.

Comment: this is just 2 lines, would have been nice, if you just posted it in comments.